# Can we run chrome app code simply as web application through local server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-app-developer-tool

I have chrome app which I run by adding it to chrome browser. My question is as it is a javascript code can I run this code using local server for ex. python SimpleHTTPServer etc? The app uses chrome serial API. I tried running it through local server but it did not get chrome.serial object. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: well you kinda answered your question, if you are using `chrome.serial` how do you expect a `chrome api` to be present else where?

Comment: In a web app you can only use web API. Currently there's no web analog for chrome.serial.